# How do I pass my FASTAPI data to the browser properly?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, fastapi

I'm creating my own scraper API using fastAPI. the problem that I have is I seem to be doing something wrong as my data(scraped data) is not showing up on the browser. I've made my scraper into a class to use it in my FastAPI app and the data is shown on my console but not on the uvicorn server via the browser. which I configured properly. I've included the browser screenshot as well.

**Scraper API**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from Scraper import scrape

app = FastAPI()
data = scrape()


@app.get("/data")
async def songs():
    return data.scrapedata()
```

**Scraper**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import pandas as pd

class scrape:

    def scrapedata(self):
        ser = Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,service=ser)
        driver.get('https://soundcloud.com/jujubucks')
        print(driver.title)

        wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()

        song_list = []

        for i in range(1, 35):
            song_contents = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='soundList__item'][{}]".format(i))
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",song_contents)
            try:    
                search = song_contents.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[contains(@class,'soundTitle__username')]/span").text
                search_song = song_contents.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[contains(@class,'soundTitle__title')]/span").text
                search_date = song_contents.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//time[contains(@class,'relativeTime')]/span").text
                search_plays = song_contents.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[contains(@class,'sc-ministats-small')]/span").text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                continue
            if search_plays == False:
                continue
            
            option ={
                'Artist': search, 
                'Song_title': search_song, 
                'Date': search_date,
                'Streams': search_plays
            }
            song_list.append(option)

        df = pd.DataFrame(song_list)
        print(df)
        driver.quit()


data = scrape()

data.scrapedata()
```

[image]

Comment: it should return something, there's no return in the `scrapedata` function

Comment: could you please clarify, I'm a bit confused. Do you mean there is nothing to return?

Comment: what should the scrapedata function should return actually, pass it in a variable and `return` it

Comment: I think its best if you make example for me because I am lost.

Comment: added explanation as an answer, check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are literally just printing your result which should be passed to your FastAPI site

It should be `return data` instead of `print(data)`

Like:

```py
    song_list.append(option)

df = pd.DataFrame(song_list)
return df
driver.quit()
```

which will be then, later, passed to the songs function of FastAPI

```py
@app.get("/data")
async def songs():
    return data.scrapedata()
```

And also, FastAPI will only return everything in JSON type, no matter if its a string, it'll end up appearing in a `application/json` like response page

So it's better to convert the dataframe into dict before passing them into the FastAPI response like

```py
return df.to_dict()
```

Or better just return the `song_list` which reduces other unnecessary function operations (but you might have to process the response content into Dataframe if u really want it to be a Dataframe)

Like:

```py
return song_list
```

Tell me if its not working...